# Overriding type defintions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a Chrome Extension in TypeScript. I have installed @types/chrome and everything seemed in order.

Now I want to use [chrome-extension-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-extension-async) which provides a Promisified version of the chrome extension objects, allowing me to async/await.

I can't seem to figure out how to enable this extension, though. The documentation just says I should add a `<script>` pointing to the extension's js file. My Chrome extension has no HTML pages, so there's no `<script>` tag.

UPDATE:
Following @basarat's advice I've stopped using @types/chrome and added `chrome-extension-async.d.ts` to my tsconfig. Typescript does not complain now, but Chrome does. Chrome sees the old chrome namespace, not the overridden one, so when it sees a `chrome.storage.sync.get` call with no callback, it complains.

If I import the extension, with something like

`import * as chromeAsync from "chrome-extension-async"`;

the import works, but I can't `await chrome.storage.sync.get('field)` because TypeScript complains (quite rightly) that I'm not passing a callback.

I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

> the import works, but I can't await chrome.storage.sync.get('field) because TypeScript complains (quite rightly) that I'm not passing a callback.

Dont use `@types/chrome` and instead use https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync/blob/master/chrome-extension-async.d.ts

## More

From the docs [image]

Comment: I've uninstalled @types/chrome and added the chrome-extension-async.d.ts to my files in tsconfig.json. Now Typescript doesn't complain but Chrome does - Chrome doesn't see chrome-extension-async at all and complains I'm not passing a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Function is also an object in TypeScript and you and make any object of type 'any'. Doing this it will accept whatever parameter you pass to this function.

try:
**< any>(chrome.storage.sync.get)()**